# Can't access NSTimer's userInfo

Tags: objective-c, ios7, automatic-ref-counting, nstimer

I have this code.

```
- (void)scheduleTimerAfterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delay
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(triggerTimer:)
                                                userInfo:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", delay]
                                                 repeats:NO];
    });
}

- (void)triggerTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Triggered timer after %@ s.", _timer.userInfo); // <-- Exception thrown!
        // Do stuff
    });
}
```

But when the timer triggers, `_timer.userInfo` causes a `Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc))`.

What have I missed here? Printing _timer at a breakpoint on the line of the exception shows that _timer is `<__NSCFTimer: 0x14ec8cb0>`. But I can't access userInfo via lldb either. I'm using ARC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>The `userInfo` should be a dictionary:</strike>

```
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delay
                                          target:self
                                        selector:@selector(triggerTimer:)
                                        userInfo:@{ @"name" : @"Zinedine Zidane",
                                                    @"age"  : @42 }
                                         repeats:NO];
```

and you obviously need to change the way you access it in the selector:

You need to retain the `userInfo` before calling `dispatch_async()`:

```
- (void)triggerTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSString *s = timer.userInfo;    // Strong reference!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Triggered timer after %@ s.", s);
        // Do stuff
    });
}
```

Comment: The documentation states that it should be id. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/userInfo

Even so, changing it to a dictionary doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: @MdaG I've updated my answer.  You'll need to access it as dictionary as well.

Comment: The problem here is, Timer fires 'triggerTimer' on mainThread and you are again asking to dispatch on maintherad. So dispatched work will be done on next runLoop. But the timer object is valid for this Runloop only.

Comment: Thanks that did it. userInfo doesn't need to be a dictionary, any NSObject will do. NSString in my case.

Comment: Your solution works because you are retaining the dictionary before the dispatch, *not* because it's a dictionary.

Comment: @Sebastian Too true.  Fixed.